# GODI installation issue

Tags: linux, ocaml, godi

I'm trying to install [GODI](http://godi.camlcity.org/godi/index.html) on linux (Ubuntu). It's a library management tool for the ocaml language. I've actually installed this before --twice, but awhile ago-- with no issues --that I can remember-- but this time I just can't figure out what I'm missing.

```
$ ./bootstrap --prefix /home/nlucaroni/godi
$ ./bootstrap_stage2
.: 1: godi_confdir: not found
Error: Command fails with code 2: /bin/sh
Failure!
```

I had added the proper directories to the path, and they show up with a quick `echo $path`, and `godi_confdir` reported as being:

```
 /home/nlucaroni/godi/etc
```

(...and the directory exists, with the godi.conf file present). So, I can't figure out why `./bootstrap_stage2` isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got closed.  It's totally a programming question.  I mean, if we can ask questions about IDEs, surely we can ask questions about installing libraries?

Comment: I closed it, since i figured it out

Comment: I didn't notice you only close when it isn't programming... i just can't accept an answer. I'll open it back up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Chris, I just figured it out. Silly mistake.

It was just a permission issue, running everything from `/tmp/` worked fine --well after enabling `GODI_BASEPKG_PCRE` in `godi.conf`. I had been running it from my home directory, you forget simple things like that at 3:00am.

--

Actually I'm having another problem. Installing `conf-opengl-6`:

GODI can't seen to find the `GL/gl.h` file, though I can --you can see that it is `Checking the suggestion`.

```
> ===> Configuring for conf-opengl-6
> Checking the suggestion
>   Include=/usr/include/GL/gl.h Library=/<GLU+GL>
> Checking /usr:
>   Include=/usr/include/GL/gl.h Library=/usr/lib/<GLU+GL>
> Checking /usr:
>   Include=/usr/local/include/GL/gl.h Library=/usr/local/lib/<GLU+GL>
> Checking /usr/local:
>   Include=/usr/local/include/GL/gl.h Library=/usr/local/lib/<GLU+GL>
> Exception: Failure "Cannot find library".
> Error: Exec error: File /home/nlucaroni/godi/build/conf/conf-opengl/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1022: Command returned with non-zero exit code
> Error: Exec error: File /home/nlucaroni/godi/build/conf/conf-opengl/./../../mk/bsd.pkg.mk, line 1375: Command returned with non-zero exit code

### Error: Command fails with code 1: godi_console
```

*edit* - Ok, this is fixed too... just needed GLU, weird since the test configuration option said everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

What is the output of `which godi_confdir`?

P.S. I remember having this exact same problem, but I don't remember precisely how I fixed it.